# Total stored potential energy of finite element mesh from nodal point displacements and strain energy density function only

Tags: finite-element, solid-mechanics

I am interested in calculating the total potential energy stored in a finite element mesh given its nodal point displacements **alone**. The forces that created the displacements are irrelevant because the objective is to calculate the strain energy stored in the mesh post-deformation.

From what I understand the total potential energy can be computed by integrating the strain energy density $W(x, \epsilon(x))$

$$
\Pi = \int_\Omega W(x, \epsilon(x)) d\Omega
$$

In a two-dimensional discrete setting

$$
\Pi = \sum_e W_e(x, \epsilon(x)) \cdot A_e
$$

where $A_e$ is the area of the element $e$. Is this correct?

If it matters the material is hyperelastic.

Comment: I'm missing something. I'm not sure what your question is - it seems you already know the answer.

Comment: @Nachiket I'm not sure if my thinking is right. For example in three-dimensions would I be multiplying $W_e$ by the volume $V_e$ of an element?

Comment: OTOH is this too simplistic if the strain is not constant throughout the element?

Comment: True. I think you just need to evaluate your first integral with the right quadrature, depending on your finite element interpolations. The integral for hyperelasticity would be analogous: the product of the First-PK tensor with F, the deformation gradient. (You should double check this, I'm saying this from memory)

Comment: Since you have the strain-energy density function, put your displacements into it and integrate it over your elastic domain.

Comment: @Nachiket Thanks. I am currently trying to figure out how to compute the deformation gradient $F$ from the nodal point displacements so that I can compute the principal invariants of the right-handed Cauchy Green deformation tensor, $F^T F$ -- but that's probably a separate question.

Comment: One step at a time. See if you can figure out how to compute the derivative of a scalar variable. $u(x) = \sum_{A}u_AN_A(x) \implies u_{,x}(x)=(\sum_{A}u_AN_A(x))_{,x}=\sum_{A}u_AN_{A,x}(x)$. The vector case is similar - deal with one component at a time.

Comment: @Nachiket I'm considering the interpolation function $u(x,y) = \alpha_1 + \alpha_2 x + \alpha_3 y + \alpha_4 xy$, from which I will solve for the $\alpha$'s. I initially favoured Lagrange polynomials but, as shown [here](https://pyfr.discourse.group/t/on-2d-lagrange-polynomials/391/2), they create bivariate polynomials of order 3, which is quite high IMO.  Which technique would you suggest?

Comment: I cannot understand the link you referred to.  Why don't you take a look at equations (3.9.1)-(3.9.9) from TJR Hughes's "The finite element method: linear static and dynamic finite element analysis"

Comment: @Nachiket Thanks. (I was overthinking it.) Now $F_{ij}^{-1} = \delta_{ij} - \frac{\partial u_i}{\partial x_j}$

Comment: That doesn't seem right. If you want $F^{-1}$ calculate $F$ and then invert it.

Comment: That's from Continuum Mechanics Volume 1 by C.S. Jog -- Equations (2.5b) and (2.6b). The point, as I understand it, is that $u(x)$ is over the deformed configuration, not the reference configuration. (Happy to continue this conversation by email if you like.)

Comment: Hmm. I've always calculated $F$ in the reference configuration. I can't see quickly that the definition of $F^{-1}$ you're using is correct.

Comment: It does seem correct.

Comment: Feel free to email me if you'd like.

Comment: @Nachiket I did a few days ago. Please check your spam bin (gok*****@gmail.com)

Answer (score 3):

The elastic energy stored in your solid is computed as

$$\Pi = \int_\Omega \sigma : \epsilon\, \mathrm{d}\Omega\, ,$$

where $\sigma$ is the stress tensor, $\epsilon$ is the strain tensor, and $:$ is the double contraction over the tensors.

When you discretize the solid, the strain energy is

$$\Pi_h = \mathbf{F}^T \mathbf{U}\, ,$$

where $h$ represents the discretization, $\mathbf{F}$ is the vector of nodal forces, and $\mathbf{U}$ is the vector of nodal displacements. Furthermore, we know that

$$\mathbf{F} = [\mathbf{K}] \mathbf{U}\, ,$$

thus, we can also compute the energy as

$$\Pi_h = \mathbf{U}^T [\mathbf{K}] \mathbf{U}\, .$$

Comment: Perhaps I don't fully appreciate your answer but nodal forces are not given -- just the nodal displacements and the strain energy density function.

Comment: @Olumide once the nodal displacements and material properties are known you can calculate $\mathbf{F}=[\mathbf{K}]\mathbf{U}$ which is commony referred to as the vector of nodal forces. In the general hyperelastic case, you won't be able to get such a nice linear relation. You would need to evaluate the integral I mentioned in the previous comment.